# how to align to right and middle in height in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview, android-switch

I have a Switch, witch is aligned to the left of a layout, 
I want to align a TextView to the right of it AND to the middle of the height of it. 
I have done two example pictures to explain it more clearly.

This is what i have (where A is the Switch, and b is the TextView):

[image]

This is what i want to achieve:

[image]

My layout code for the switch is:

```
<Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CIR"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:checked="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/newProject_switch"
        android:layout_below="@+id/newProject_networkId"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        />
```

My layout code for the TextView is:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Best Effort"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newProject_switch"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newProject_switch"
        />
```

Comment: Post your complete code for layout.

Comment: You can use a relativeLayout, then set the TextView to the left of it and center vertical

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this way.

Remove Extra `Margin` you set in your `Switch` and use `android:gravity="center_vertical`. and set `TextView` to `android:gravity="center_vertical|right"` so that it is right side and vertically center.

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/newProject_switch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="CIR" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newProject_switch"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newProject_switch"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:text="Best Effort"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: specifying the , android:layout_height, fixed it for me. thnx !

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your textview

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have remove `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` and add `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` to your `Switch`.
And change `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"` to `android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"` in your `TextView`

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e4e4e4"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        >
        <Switch
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="CIR"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:checked="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/newProject_switch"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newProject_networkId"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Best Effort"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/newProject_switch"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/newProject_switch"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]